# WDK10 + Visual Studio 2015 + WDK Sample = Failed to run compiled driver on Win8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1, driver, wdk

Everyone.

My OS is Win8.1

I compiled the following driver Windows-driver-samples-master\network\trans\inspect in MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise using default project settings:

Platform Toolset = WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0

Target OS Version = Windows10

Target Platform = Universal

and s.o.

I installed compiled driver via inspect.inf and tried to run via "net start inspect" from "cmd" ran as administrator but failed.

I have the following error:

"System error 2 has occured.

The system cannot find the file specified."

On Windows 10 it works fine.

Can any one advice me how to build sample driver to run one on win7+?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: compilpe the driver for Windows 8.1 and not Windows 10